# Count the number of dimes?

Tags: systems-of-equations, word-problem

You are given a bag with 100 coins.  The bag only has pennies, dimes and half-dollars.  The bag has at least one of each coin.  The total value of the coins in the bag is worth $5,  How many dimes are in the bag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be the number of pennies, $D$ the number of dimes, and $H$ the number of half-dollars.

We have $P+D+H=100$ and $P+10D+50H=500$.

Subtract the former from the latter and we have $9D+49H=400$.

There is only one integer pair solution $(D,H)$ to that last equation, and that solves the problem.

Comment: So, does this mean that d=39? I was actually confused in the last equation.

Comment: Yes, $D=39$ and $H=1$ (so you can figure out $P$ too)

Comment: Modulo $9$ that equation is $4H\equiv4$